# How to get all the groups from photo library, like native?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, avfoundation

I Have create custom photo library like native and everything is working fine, But I am not able to get Videos,Favorites,Panoramas (group), How can I get this same as like native photo library ? I have use `ALAssetsGroupAll` to get groups from the library and show it in tableview like native. so please help me how to get Videos,Favorites,Panoramas (group)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should enumerate all the groups available. i.e something like this

```
ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock resultsBlock = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)  {
    if (group){

    }
};

ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureBlock = ^(NSError *error){

};

NSUInteger type =
ALAssetsGroupLibrary | ALAssetsGroupAlbum | ALAssetsGroupEvent |
ALAssetsGroupFaces | ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream;
[self.assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:type
                                  usingBlock:resultsBlock
                                failureBlock:failureBlock];
```